# set content in scrollview ? Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I have an `Xml` that add `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView` by `programmatically`.When i add `Text` with `OnclickButton` for first time show me message but for 2nd time get me crash :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtInpuConversation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="Text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Click" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code :

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String Medtconversation;
    EditText edtconversation;
    TextView txtviewUser;
    LinearLayout rilative;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    LinearLayout firstLinearLayout;
    ScrollView sclView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtconversation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInpuConversation);
        sclView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollID);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);



         final Context context = this;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Medtconversation = edtconversation.getText().toString();
                txtviewUser = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtviewUser.setText(Medtconversation);
                relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
                firstLinearLayout= new LinearLayout(context);
                LayoutParams LLParamsT = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(LLParamsT);
                relativeLayout.addView(txtviewUser,
                        new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                firstLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                firstLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
                firstLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

Crash here now======>sclView.addView(firstLinearLayout, new
                          LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                edtconversation.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need that when i `click` on `Button` and send message for 2nd time create a new `RelativeLayout` in `LinearLayout` for show.(In `scrollView`)

[image]

Error :

```
    AndroidRuntime
MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmmmm. I recommend that you using from `table` and you can add `programmatically` your `TextView` and etc. simply :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String Medtconversation;
    EditText edtconversation;
    TextView txtviewUser;
    TextView txtviewUserT;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    LinearLayout firstLinearLayout;
    TableRow tr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtconversation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInpuConversation);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
        final Context context = this;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Medtconversation = edtconversation.getText().toString();
                txtviewUser = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtviewUserT = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtviewUserT.setText("OK");
                txtviewUser.setText(Medtconversation);
                 tr = new TableRow(context);
                 tr.addView(txtviewUser);
                 tr.addView(txtviewUserT);
                 tl.addView(tr);
                edtconversation.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your `XML` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tbl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtInpuConversation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="Text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Click" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new LinearLayout and RelativeLayout only once (inside `onCreate`), however you add them multiple times. Instead create new instances from inside of the `onClick` method:

```
    final Context context = this;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LinearLayout firstLinearLayout= new LinearLayout(context);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
            ...
            firstLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now get me Crash here :  sclView.addView(firstLinearLayout, new
              LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: @A.A then create a new firstLinearLayout too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know!What can i do ?

Comment: @A.A did you try my code? If so and you still get an error, please update your question with the new code AND a **full** error message.

Comment: .MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:61) AND AndroidRuntime

Comment: @A.A FULL message! In your question, not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to add the `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView`
- Then add the `relative layout` to the `LinearLayout`

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String Medtconversation;
    EditText edtconversation;
    TextView txtviewUser;
    LinearLayout rilative;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    LinearLayout firstLinearLayout;
    ScrollView sclView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtconversation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInpuConversation);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        sclView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollID);

         firstLinearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);

        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Medtconversation = edtconversation.getText().toString();
                txtviewUser = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtviewUser.setText(Medtconversation);

                LayoutParams LLParamsT = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(LLParamsT);
                relativeLayout.addView(txtviewUser,
                        new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



                firstLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                firstLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

                sclView.addView(firstLinearLayout);
                firstLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

                sclView.addView(firstLinearLayout, new
                          LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                edtconversation.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```